# How to add imageview inside textview or add textview inside imageview, android?

Tags: android, textview, imageview

I was wondering if it is possible to add textview inside imageview or vice-versa.
Is it possible?
If yes then how?

I want to make this at runtime

Comment: use compound textview for text and image in textview.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?  Do you want to insert image as part of the textview's content? Or do you want to have an image as the background of your textview?

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way I think is to setCompoundDrawables via XML attributes

```
android:drawableLeft
android:drawableTop
android:drawableRight
android:drawableBottom.
```

Example:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_navigation_chevron_right"
    android:text="Next "
    android:textSize="20dp" />
```

Result:

[image: textView with image inside]

Answer (score 3):

```
ImageSpan ispan = new ImageSpan(context, yourresourceid);
text.setSpan(ispan, index, index + strLength, 0);
```

OR

```
    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById( R.id.TextView );
    Spannable spannable = (Spannable)textView.getText();
    StyleSpan boldSpan = new StyleSpan( Typeface.BOLD );
    spannable.setSpan( boldSpan, 41, 52, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE );

    TextView textView2 = (TextView)findViewById( R.id.TextView2 );
    SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder( "Here's a smiley  " );
    Bitmap smiley = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getResources(), R.drawable.emoticon );
    ssb.setSpan( new ImageSpan( smiley ), 16, 17, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE ); 
    textView2.setText( ssb, BufferType.SPANNABLE );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use setCompoundDrawables.... methods from TextView. There are many versions of this method. Look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawables%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29).

Answer (score -1):

Try to use frame layout

hERE IS THE SAMPLE CODE

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/day">

    <FrameLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
         >
  <ImageView  
    android:id="@+id/ImageView01"  
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:src="@drawable/pinkrose"  


 >
 </ImageView>  
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
     android:textColor="#ff00ff00"
    android:textSize="40dp"  
    android:text="@string/top_text" />  
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:text="@string/bottom_text"  
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"  
    android:gravity="right"  
    android:textColor="#ff00ff00"
    android:textSize="50dp" />
```

AND FOR RUNTIME  THIS IS SAMPLE

```
     public class FrameExample extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LinearLayout ll=new LinearLayout(this);
     ll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
             LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
     ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        ll.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bunch);
        ll.setGravity(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    FrameLayout fl=new FrameLayout(this);

    fl.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams
                        (FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    ImageView iv=new ImageView(this);
    iv.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams
                        (FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                       FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    iv.setPadding(30, 30, 30, 30);
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.pinkrose);
    fl.addView(iv);
    TextView tv1=new TextView(this);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params= new FrameLayout.LayoutParams
    ( LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    tv1.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
    tv1.setText("this is upper part of image");
    tv1.setTextColor(0xffff0000);
    tv1.setTextSize(40);
    tv1.setLayoutParams(params);
    fl.addView(tv1);
    TextView tv2=new TextView(this);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params1= new FrameLayout.LayoutParams
     ( LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    tv2.setLayoutParams(params1);

    tv2.setGravity(android.view.Gravity.BOTTOM);
    tv2.setText("this is lower part of image");
    tv2.setTextColor(0xff00ff00);
    tv2.setTextSize(40);
    fl.addView(tv2);


    ll.addView(fl);
    setContentView(ll);
}
```

}