# How to make menu button in Android?

Tags: android-layout, button, settings

I want to make a button looking as in the picture:
[Source: Settingsapp from Huawei](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6Dps.png)

I don't want to use a graphic for the arrow if that is possible, but use a special component which uses this arrow by default.

Comment: Here I found what I wanted to do:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/31370038/7519497

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ListView to make a button with Images and Texts or can put your items in a LinearLayout